# Need to update schema root element name and schema field name for DXA upgrade 1.5 to 2.2

Tags: dxa, core-service, dxa2.2, dxa-1.5, sites-9.1

we need to update schema root element name and schema field name for DXA upgrade 1.5 to 2.2 so that semantic mapping in web application starts working with dxa 2.2

Following are my questions:

1. if we update schema root element name using core service script and then using script if start open and save component based on that schema will there be any chance of content loss/ corruption of component?
2. is there any need of update schema field xml names to camel case so that semantic mapping works in web application models? or will web application work without camel case format?
3. if it is required, then we can update schema field XML name using script and synchronize the components using script by open and save them. will there be any chance of content loss/ corruption of component?

Answer (score 1):

1. In general, changing the root element name of Schemas on which a lot of Components are based is a rather high-impact change which should be avoided if possible.  Note that DXA has a [retrofit mode](https://docs.rws.com/784837/476168/sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-2/regular-or-retrofit-modes-for-mapping-view-models-to-------------sdl-tridion-sites-schemas) which deals with this situation without requiring changes to Schema root element names.
2. Again, you want to avoid CM Schema changes. Instead, you can use `SemanticProperty` annotations on you View Models to map View Model properties to CM field names (if the default semantics don't work for you).
3. Again, try to stay away from CM Schema changes. The Core Service does provide APIs to apply some (typical) Schema changes to content based on the Schema, but it won't be able to deal with field name changes.